# Integral over a volume of (mass density)$\cdot$(magnitude of displacement field)?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, continuum-mechanics

> Let $u = u(X,t) = \varphi(X,t)-X$ be the displacement field. Define the quantity
>   $$\psi = 1/2\int_\Omega \rho u^Tu~\mathrm dX$$
>   where $\rho$ is the mass density.

So if it were velocity instead of displacement field, this would equal kinetic energy. I'm struggling to figure out what it is with displacement though, like what this would represent physically. Maybe nothing? If I'm being asked to define the quantity, maybe I can define it however I like? Displacement energy of some sort?

Comment: What do you mean by displacement field? The usual context of the word "displacement field" is in electromagnetism - the electric displacement field $\mathbf{D}$.

Comment: It seems sort of like you are calculating the total kinetic energy of an object in a separate reference frame moving with velocity $X$. Is this correct?

Comment: Suppose that X represents the spatial coordinates of a particle of material in a deformable body at time t = 0, suppose $\phi (X,t)$ represents the spatial coordinates of this same particle of material at time t, after the body has been deformed.  We use X as a label to identify the specific particle we are talking about.  Then the displacment of the particle at time t, relative to its location at time zero is $u(X,t)=\phi(X,t)-X$

Comment: Thank you for the tag changes Arturo, and also for the clarification Chester - sorry for not being clear before

Comment: Is the equation you presented for $\psi$ something you just dreamed up and were wondering what it might mean, or is it something you actually saw somewhere in the literature.  Because, as written, I can see no significant physical meaning for this quantity.

Comment: Ah, I wish haha. This is a problem taken from "Introduction to Mathematical Modeling" by J. Tinsley Oden. Here it is from the book: http://imgur.com/a/zmvL9

Comment: It looks like, to get the equation in this reference, you start out by dotting the stress equilibrium equation (including the inertial terms, but not the body force terms) with the displacement field, and then integrating over the volume of the body.  Presumably, P is the stress tensor.  The integral over area in the equation can be changed to a volume integral by using  the divergence theorem.

Answer (score 0):

It is elastic potential energy. The integral you write down is a continuum version of Hookes' law. The $u^T u$ indicates that the energy is quadratic in the displacement. The mass density is a measure of how many particles are displaced.

Comment: This is not correct.  The stored elastic energy is quadratic in the strains, not in the displacements.

Comment: You are correct, it cannot be because a constant displacement field, carries no potential energy.